# How to show the values in the LOOP for every 10 second in java

Tags: java, shell, loops, servlets, while-loop

I have a while loop where in it constructs a JAVA String by appending the output from a shell script.

```
System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
refreshString = refreshString + s;
System.out.println(s);
}
```

This shell script takes 2hrs to execute. Is there a way by which I can grab the string every 10 seconds(Snapshot of the current string)? I am developing a JAVA application where in I need to display that string on the browser every 10 seconds.(I am doing that by using Auto Page Refresh Library. The page automatically refreshes.)

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
...
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
...
out.println(refreshString);
```

Now my page has to display current "refreshString" every time the page refreshes.

Just let me know if my question isn't clear.

Comment: Maybe us Thread.sleep()?

Comment: Are you asking me to use Threads? How can I get the snapshot of the string in a while loop with Threads?

Comment: In loop use Thread.sleep(10000); end every time when loop run it make 10 seconds pause. When you write simple "Hello world" you already use one thread.

Comment: How about _every n lines of input_ instead of _every 10 seconds_ ? for sure don't use `thread.sleep()`

Comment: So you are asking me to pause my while loop execution and print the current string value.?? @disable1992

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use file. Your script writes the output to a file. Your servlet then reads this file whenever it is called.

Comment: Do you think is it possible for me to write the contents to a file and then retrieve it from there at the same time?

Comment: The script writes (appends) file, while the servlet reads the file. Thus, I don't see any potential problem. But, we need to try it to be certain.

Answer (score 2):

What about... Every ten seconds it will print your string and it doesnt need many changes!

```
long ini = System.currentTimeMillis();
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
    refreshString = refreshString + s;
    if(System.currentTimeMillis() - ini >= 10 * 1000){
        ini = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

edited: sorry you meant every ten seconds!
Hope it helps!

Comment: System.out.println(s) prints the string on the Tomcat console. And what I need is exactly similar to that. I need my browser to display what tomcat console displays.

Comment: then you have to store it in a file, memcached.. anywhere! So you can read this stored data and print it in your web page everytime the client ask's.

Comment: And the output on the console is huge. It changes drastically.

Comment: Then do not use a file, since it may take too much disk usage. Think about the size of the console output. How much is it? 1, 10, 1000Mb? Maybe you want to store it in the java heap and maybe its too big to be there and you need to use any external help as [memcached](http://memcached.org/) which is basically a simple way to store data for a short time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {

    public void run() {
        while (true){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                System.out.println(myString);
                myString = "";
            } catch (Exception e){}                
        }
    }
};

thread.start();        
for (int i=0; ; i++){
    myString += i;
    // Do other stuff
}
```